# how do I use regex to match expressions such as b1, b2, ... thru b15, but no further?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I am using Java, Eclipse on a Mac running MacOs Mojave.
Seems this would be easy, but I have spent 4-5 hours on it.
Need to recognize the following strings: `b1, b2, b3, ... b14, b15`.
Have tried "`^b1[012345]{1}$ | ^b[1-9]?$`
and others:
`(^b1[012345]{1}$) | (^b[1-9]{1}$)`

`^b(1 | 2| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | | 13 | 14 | 15){1}$`
and even
`^b( '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7'... | '15'){1}$`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\bb(?:1[0-5]|[1-9])\b
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MO0vj5/2)**

In JAVA, you need to escape `\` with another `\`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - matches a word boundary
- `b` - matches the letter `b`
- `(?:1[0-5]|\d)` - matches 1 followed by a number in the range `0-5` OR matches a single digit number from `1-9`
- `\b` - matches a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  But it didn't work; I fiddled with it and could not get into work.  The following is verbose, but it works:

```
String first = pageText.substring(0, 1);
String rest = pageText.substring(1, pageText.length());
String pattern = "[^0-9]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(rest);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "<html>Only b followed by a number between 1 and “
            + “15 in the page number field",
            "Page Number Is Not Recognizable",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
}
int intRest = Integer.parseInt(rest); // string to integer
 if ((intRest > 0 && intRest < 16) && (first.equals("b"))) {
      // valid
```